# How can I have quick access to a file?

Tags: shortcuts

I need a shortcut, menu entry of some type (not a desktop shortcut) that readily allows me to access a particular file on the disk.

I'm thinking something like when I pin a .txt file to the start menu in windows.   Is that possible?

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open .gtk-bookmarks (in your home directory) and add a URI to that file like:

```
file:///home/user/file.txt To-dos
file:///home/user/anotherfile.txt Meetings
```

It will add a shortcut to your places/bookmarks menu and call them 'To-dos' and 'Meetings' respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard shortcuts work well for me.  I have ALT+number1 to open up a program.

Comment: Thanks. It would be more helpful if you provided the details on how to set up the shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in Unity, use the System Settings command in the logout menu to get to the Keyboard settings and look in its Shortcuts tab. You'll add your Alt+1 shortcut, or whatever you like, in the Custom Shortcuts list.

A convenient way to open a document without customizing is to press Alt-F2 and type the name of the file.